# how to return a value in PHP Factorial Program

Tags: php

I am working on one of my assignment for Factorial Program. I am struck on one point.

Fact.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="FactCalc.php" method="post">
Enter a Number: <input type="text" name="number">
<input type="submit" Value="Calculate Factorial">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

FactCalc.php

```
<?php
  $num = $_POST["number"];
  $factorial = 1;
  for ($x=$num; $x>=1; $x--)
  {
   $factorial = $factorial * $x;
   }
   echo "Factorial of $num is $factorial";
?>
```

this program is running fine. I want to return $factorial to Fact.php and display it there below the text box. I am kind of struck here, can you please help.

Comment: Leave the form's `action` attribute empty and let the form post to itself. Create a `<div>` under the textbox, assign an ID to it, style it however you want. Now output `$num` inside that `<div>`. Simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["number"]))
{
  $_POST["number"] = ($_POST["number"] * 1);
  include "FactCalc.php";
}  
?> 

<form action="FactCalc.php" method="post">      
  <p>
    Enter a Number: 
    <input type="text" name="number">
    <input type="submit" Value="Calculate Factorial"> 

  <?php
  if (isset($factorial))
  {
    echo "</p><p>Factorial of $num is $factorial";
  }
  ?>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX for this but here is a simple way, hope you get an idea...

```
<?php
  $result="";
  if(isset($_POST['ispost']) && $_POST['ispost']=="y"){
   $num = $_POST["number"];
   $factorial = 1;
   for ($x=$num; $x>=1; $x--)
   {
    $factorial = $factorial * $x;
   }
   $result="Factorial of ".$num." is ".$factorial;
  }
?> 



    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ispost" value="y" />
    Enter a Number: <input type="text" name="number" />
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate Factorial /">
    </form>
    <?php print($result); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the AJAX enabled, more eloquent solution.  This answer anticipates potential conflict problems with the "$", and potential caching problems with jQuery.get or post

```
Fact.php:

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="ispost" value="y" />
            Enter a Number: <input type="text" name="number" id="number" />
            <input type="button" id="factorial_button" value="Calculate Factorial /">
        </form>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#factorial_button").click(function(){
                var number = jQuery("#number").val();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "FactCalc.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {   
                        "number":number,
                    },
                    dataType : "html",
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        jQuery("#result").html("retrieving information...");
                    },               
                    success: function( data ) {
                        jQuery("#result").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                        jQuery("#result").html("Ajax error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

FactCalc.php:

```
<?php
$num = $_POST["number"];
$factorial = 1;

for ($x=$num; $x>=1; $x--)
{
    $factorial = $factorial * $x;
}

echo "Factorial of $num is $factorial";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

Fact.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["number"]))
{
  $num = $_POST["number"];
  $factorial = 1;
  for ($x=$num; $x>=1; $x--)
  {
    $factorial = $factorial * $x;
  }
}
else
  $factorial = "";
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    Enter a Number: <input type="text" name="number">
    <input type="submit" Value="Calculate Factorial">
<?php
  if($factorial)
    echo "Factorial of $num is $factorial";
?>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can't "share" the variable between FactCalc.php and Fact.php

Answer (score 0):

```
**try this very easy to use this factorial**
<?php
    $fact=1;
    for($i=5;$i>=1;$i--)
    {
    $fact=$fact*$i;


    }

    echo $fact;
?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @bono its a perfect answer can easily use and execute in php

Comment: I know it is, but You have to have future readers in mind as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function factorial($number) { 

        if ($number < 2) { 
            return 1; 
        } else { 
            return ($number * factorial($number-1)); 


 } 
}
```

Check [code demo](https://www.phprun.org/c1c3Z2) here